# compact operators and finite dimentional spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Let $Q_n$ a finite dimentional space. Since any finite rank operator is compact, it's true that any linear operator $K:Q_n\to Q_n$ is compact 'cause $\dim(R(K))<\infty$?

Comment: I think that $K$ must be bounded, so $\{Ku_n\}$ is bounded if $\{u_n\}\subset Q_n$ is a bounded sequence. By the bolzano witerass theorem, we get that has a convergent subsequence and thus, $K$ is compact.

Comment: Is Q_n a finite dimensional linear subspace of a vector space? Is $K$ a linear operator?

Comment: Yes, $Q_n$ is a finite linear subspace of a vector space and $K$ is linear. Do you think that it's correct?

Comment: Yes of course. If $Q_n\subseteq L$ and $L$ is a Hausdorff topological vector space (e.g., a Banach space), then $K\colon Q_n\to Q_n$ takes bounded subsets of $Q_n$ into bounded subsets of $Q_n$. The closure of a bounded subset of a Hausdorff finite dimensional space is compact because Hausdorff finite dimensional spaces are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Comment: $K$ must be bounded or simply we must asume that $K$ is linear?

Comment: just linear. A linear function from a finite dimensional Hausdorff topological vector space is continuous, bounded, compact.

Comment: Ok, thanks for you help! =)

Comment: @RabeeTourky you can post that comment as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A linear function from a finite dimensional Hausdorff topological vector space to itself is continuous, bounded, and compact. This is because a finite dimensional Hausdorff topological vector is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a linear function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous. Now closed bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are compact and visa versa. So it takes bounded sets to sets whose closure is compact.